# Understanding the proof of runtime O(N)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am interested on knowing the reasoning behind clearing the following equation. Can you please refer what are the laws applied to solved the equation?

Let $P = 2^{\log N}$. By the definition of $\log_2$, we can write this as $\log_2 P = \log_2N$. This means that $P=N$.

$$P = 2^{\log N}\\
\log_2 P  = \log_2N\\
P = N\\
2^{\log N} = N$$

Can you please point me to the resources to understand how to clear the equation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

I am confused with your title, that's why I will just answer your question from the body of your post.

---

This law of logarithm is similar to the exponential one, which is:

> If $a^{x} = a^{y}$ for $a > 0$ and $x,y \neq 0$, then $x=y$.

In your case, you are asking for an explanation of the statement

> Let $P = 2^{\log_{2}N}$. By the definition of $\log_{2}$, we can write $\log_{2}P = \log_{2}N$. This means that $P = N$.

To be consistent, we will use the page [Logarithms](https://brilliant.org/wiki/logarithms) from Brilliant as our resource.
\begin{align*}
   P &= 2^{\log_{2}N} && \text{(given)} \\
   \log_{2}P &= \log_{2}\left(2^{\log_{2}N}\right) &&\text{(logarithms on both sides)} \\
   \log_{2}P &= (\log_{2}N)(\log_{2}2) && (\log_a(b^{c}) = c\log_{a}b) \\
   \log_{2}P &= (\log_{2}N)(1) && (\log_{a}a=1) \\
   \log_{2}P &= \log_{2}N && \text{(simplify)} \\
   2^{\log_{2}P} &= 2^{\log_{2}N} && \text{(raise both sides by 2)} \\
   P &= N && (a^{\log_{a}b}=b )
\end{align*}